# VSTO Ribbon Combo Box Text Changed Event Call back

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in, outlook-addin

Am creating the VS Outlook Addin.

how to get the Text changes event of combo box. I want to call my API to retrieve data while user enter some text in the combo box

```
          <comboBox id="cmbUsers" label="Users" showImage="false" 
               getItemCount="OnGetItemCount"
              getItemLabel="OnGetItemLabel"
              onChange="OnChange"
                getText="GetText"
                getKeytip="GetKeytip"/>
```

I tried with OnChange Call back, but it doesn't work. But in Ribbon Designer i can see the TextChange event.

How to use callback event for text change

```
 [ComVisible(true)]
public class Ribbon : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
{
    private Office.IRibbonUI ribbon;

    public Ribbon()
    {
    }

    #region IRibbonExtensibility Members

    public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
    {
        return GetResourceText("UserOutlookAddin.Ribbon.xml");
    }

    #endregion

    #region Ribbon Callbacks
    //Create callback methods here. For more information about adding callback methods, select the Ribbon XML item in Solution Explorer and then press F1

    public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
    {
        this.ribbon = ribbonUI;



    }

    public void OnActionCallback(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        if (control.Id == "checkBox1")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You clicked " + control.Id);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You clicked a different control.");
        }
    }
    public void OnGetItemCount(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("##### Am OnGetItemCount");
    }
    public void OnGetItemLabel(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("##### Am OnGetItemLabel");
    }
    public void OnChange(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("##### Am OnChange");
    }
    public void GetText(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("##### Am GetText");
    }
    public void GetKeytip(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("##### Am GetKeytip");
    }

    #endregion

    #region Helpers

    private static string GetResourceText(string resourceName)
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string[] resourceNames = asm.GetManifestResourceNames();
        for (int i = 0; i < resourceNames.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (string.Compare(resourceName, resourceNames[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                using (StreamReader resourceReader = new StreamReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceNames[i])))
                {
                    if (resourceReader != null)
                    {
                        return resourceReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Can you post the C# code related to `OnChange`?

Comment: @haindl yes, i updated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the signature of the `onChange` callback from

```
public void OnChange(Office.IRibbonControl control)
```

to

```
public void OnChange(Office.IRibbonControl control, string text)
```

Now it should get called.

Additionally you should change the signatures of `getItemCount`, `getItemLabel`, `getText` and `getKeytip` from

```
public void OnGetItemCount(Office.IRibbonControl control)
public void OnGetItemLabel(Office.IRibbonControl control)
public void GetText(Office.IRibbonControl control)
public void GetKeytip(Office.IRibbonControl control)
```

to

```
public int OnGetItemCount(Office.IRibbonControl control)
public string OnGetItemLabel(Office.IRibbonControl control, int index)
public string GetText(Office.IRibbonControl control)
public string GetKeytip(Office.IRibbonControl control)
```